# Is there any way to ACK tuples in a part of Storm bolts

Tags: apache-storm

As it's inefficiently to ack all messages in Storm, among the whole components of my topology, only some of them needs to guarantee message processing, and I'd like to know is there a proper way to do this.

For instance, I have a `TimingBolt` which takes tick tuple to make the job work under a specific cycle:

```java
// TimingBolt
@Override
public void execute(Tuple input) {
    if (TupleUtils.isTick(input)) {
        collector.emit(streamA, input, new Values("Tick"));
    } else {
        collector.emit(streamB, new Values("Message"));
    }
}
```

I want to guarantee the `"Tick"` message be sent explicitly once to the bolt after `TimingBolt`

```java
// The AggregateBolt after TimingBolt
@Override
public void execute(Tuple input) {
    if (input.getString(0).equals("Tick")) {
        collector.emit(new Values("Get Tick"));
        collector.ack();
    } else {
        // do something else
        collector.emit(new Values("Not Tick"));
    }
}
```

and I hope that bolts except `TimingBolt` and `AggregateBolt` could be out of range of the `ACK` tree.

The document http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html does not show anything about this matter. Is this a valid scene, or is starting ack from spout the only way to make the acker work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start from the spout.

To be clear, you're not guaranteed message delivery with what's called "a reliable topology". Instead you're guaranteed that either a tuple and all of it's "descendant tuples" are completely delivered and processed or that the spout will be notified of the failure.  Failed messages can be automatically re-emitted, but ultimately there is a small window in which a tuple is no longer retried.  In order for that to work, the spout has some reliable tuple behavior that bolts do not:  (1) the ability to emit an object id with a tuple and (2) methods that are called with that id when the tuple ultimately succeeds or fails (ack(id) and fail(id), respectively).  As bolts don't have those behaviors, you can't start reliable tuple processing from a bolt.

Consider directly configuring your second bolt with TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. The problem comes from the point that the second bolt could not do anything until the first bolt finished some batch job, and I also have a third bolt which waits for the second bolt finishes something. Those things has nothing to do with time, and that's why tick tuple could not be used in bolts after the first bolt.

Comment: You might consider making the batch job asynchronous from the topology.  The first bolt submits the batch job and stops.  No bolts follow the first bolt.  Instead, have a second spout that polls on nextTuple() to see whether any of the batch jobs have completed and if so, emit an actable tuple representing that completed job to what was the second bolt.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point, but how could the second spout know when the first bolt stopped? you know, storm cluster cannot share resources directly among different machines.

Comment: I don't know enough of your implementation to know, but a remote-able service, accessible by some sort of remote API could both submit jobs and  subsequently query their status.

Comment: Do you mean that first bolt could write its status to a remote service, and the second spout keep listening to the service to get the status?